# How to sort a list into values closes to 0

Tags: python

I have a list that is `myList = [1, 3, 5, 2.5, -3, -0.5]`

How would I sort the list so that I would get `[-0.5, 1, 2.5, 3, -3, 5]`

I've tried using `min()` but that only outputs one value, and I need a list

My code is:

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 2.5, -3, -0.5]
>>> sortedList = function(myList)
>>> print(sortedList)
[-0.5, 1, 2.5, 3, -3, 5]
```

Comment: You want to sort *by* distance from zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to sort by the *absolute value*, which you can compute with the `abs` function.

```
>>> myList = [1, 3, 5, 2.5, -3, -0.5]
>>> sorted(myList, key=abs)
[-0.5, 1, 2.5, 3, -3, 5]
```